# Sql query for a particular year and the previous year's data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Wondering how can I get data for any year and its prior year's when a year is given in where clause. Example: If i give 2012 as year in where clause, I should get both 2012 and 2011's data. This is in SQL Server 2008.

```
Select * from TableA where Year = 2012
```

but i want for 2011 in the same query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx), which allows you to define a list:

```
Select * from TableA where Year IN (2011, 2012);
```

Comment: (@Year and @Year-1) sounds good. I did not know about using "IN". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to put the constant year in once, you could do this:

```
Select *
from TableA
where 2012 in (Year, Year + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already thought of this but you should explicitly state the column names instead of 
`Select *`

Anyway another option is to declare and set the year, then modify your `WHERE` clause.

```
DECLARE @SelectedYear INT
SET @SelectedYear = 2012
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Year = @SelectedYear OR Year = (@SelectedYear-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a have single variable you can do it the following 2 ways

```
DECLARE @year AS INT = 2012
SELECT *
FROM tablea
WHERE MyYear = @year OR MyYear = (@year-1)
```

or could you this

```
DECLARE @year AS INT = 2012
SELECT *
FROM tablea
WHERE MyYear BETWEEN ((@year-1) AND @year)
```